Hide jwt with angular
I have a question regarding the security of my application.
I’m not an expert, far from it, and I’ve been tinkering for months to make something acceptable, and now I’m nearing the end.
I’ve hosted my application, but I still have a concern: when I make any request to my backend, I can see the JWT and the backend address in the console.
At first, I didn’t pay much attention to it, but after visiting other sites and inspecting the console, I don’t see any tokens (and for the backend address, I'm not sure).
My application is in Angular.
Is there any way to hide the token to increase security? An interceptor? Should I modify my services?
Thanks in advance for your help.

I see a lot of confusion here. Have a look here

Thanks @JacopoSciampi i will check it :)

if the token is stored in a cookie, then make server set HTTP and secure
https://really-simple-ssl.com/definition/what-are-secure-cookies/

this is about the security of your users... to help them stay secure, keep everything same-site/domain.  Also mitigate any XSS or CSRF vulnerabilities.  The user (or user-agent) must have knowledge of their own credentials and where to send them.  If you want to secure things a bit more, use PKCE so the client has it's own "secret" that ties the client to the token.
